# YouTube video upload through storage server url of the video

Tags: php, video, youtube

I need to upload a video to YouTube but without the video being on my web server. I have videos on a separate storage server, and the PHP is on a web server, I understand and got it working to upload a video to YouTube which is in my public web server folder.

It's simply as you only need to provide the location of the file, like `$videoPath=sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir').'/web/tmp.mp4'`, however, going on with this code my web server would have to download the file from my storage server and then set the path of the video, but that would lead to too much bandwidth usage of my web server. What I'd like to do is something like `$videoPath="http://storageserverurl.com/tmp.mp4"` but that isn't possible.

Here is the piece of code that downloads the file to the web server and sends it to YouTube, it's working without problems.

```
file_put_contents("tmp.mp4", file_get_contents("http://storageserver.com/tmp.mp4"));
$videoPath=sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir').'/web/tmp.mp4';
```

I'd like it to be something like `$videoPath="http://storageserver.com/tmp.mp4";`

The rest of the code is the sample code given by Google. I'm using PHP 5.6.3 with symfony 1.4.

Comment: Are you playing the video through a Flash plugin? If so, presumably you should work on streaming it via HTTP directly from the storage server. At present you seem to be copying it to your web server. You seem aware of this though: "What I'd like to do is something like `$videoPath="http://storageserverurl.com/tmp.mp4"` but that isn't possible". Can you explain a bit more _why_ it is not possible?

Comment: I don't know, it seems impossible for fopen to read the file directly from the storage server.

Comment: Fix that problem, then (and show the related code). Are you wanting to retrieve it via PHP and stream it via the same web server that renders the page? I wonder if you can just stream it directly from the other server to the browser, by declaring a relaxation of the Same Origin domain rules?